# place() when making buttons from list

Tags: python-3.x, tkinter

I am trying to figure out how to specify placement of buttons when populating from a list...

Example:

```
commands = ['new','save','load']
for c in commands:
     c = Button(root, text  = c)
     c.place()
```

And I get no buttons... 
Is this even possible?
 Thanks

Edit:

```
commands = ['new','save','load']
rely = .15
for c in commands:
     c = Button(root, text  = c)
     c.place(relx = .01, rely = rely,     relheight = .2, relwidth = .98)
     rely += .21
```

Does the trick quite nicely.

Solved.

Comment: `.place()` with no parameters is not very useful - even if its default values did place the Button with a usable size at a visible location, it would place *all* of your Buttons exactly on top of each other.  `.pack()` and `.grid()` are vastly more useful ways to use Tkinter; both will produce usable results with no parameters, although you're likely to need to specify some options to get the results you want.

Comment: I am not interested in .pack or .grid. I left parameters out of the code example due to the fact that if you set the parameters it places them on to of each other. I tried a separate hash in place of rely to specify multiple y locations and receive the error

Comment: Expected floating point number but received 0.15 0.36 0.57

Comment: This is the disadvantage of using `place` - you need to do all of the math yourself. `pack` and `grid` require much less work.

Comment: That may be true but it did not answer my question on whether or not it could be done.  As I have stated I am not interested in pack or grid as I want to have much finer control of the layout.

Comment: Now to address the issue of assignment of function to each button and I'm golden.